# Multiple Tables - Lowest Value based on Where clause

Tags: sql

Currently have 3 tables with the following columns,

```
Table 1
item_id | cost_price

Table 2 
item_id | cost_price

Table 3
item_id | cost_price
```

Need to sort by lowest value between the three tables where the clause is to sort by the item_id. The item_id is shared between all 3 tables.

I know its probably a subquery, with a INNER join? But I'm just not sure how to write it...

```sql
SELECT table1.cost_price, table2.cost_price, table3.cost_price FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON table1.item_id= table2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3
ON table3.item_id= table1.item_id
```

I'm hoping to sort by the lowest cost_Price out of the query.. But I'm not sure if I should use inner join..

Comment: Do you want the lowest total price and all values related to that? Or, sort by price ascending?  Also, which SQL are you using?  Transact? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm using mySQL, and the total lowest price out of all 3 tables is the goal.Sorry if this is unclear :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `union all`?

```
select item_id, cost_price from table1
union all
select item_id, cost_price from table2
union all
select item_id, cost_price from table3
order by cost_price;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,

Thats not exactly what I'm looking for as I want to find the lowest price between the 3 tables. That would only give me the output of all of them orderd by Cost_price per itemID?

Comment: @8bitmagic . . . You would add `fetch first 1 row only` or whatever is appropriate for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something with a CASE statement (untested):

```
SELECT ABC.item_id
,   CASE
        WHEN ABC.t1_min_price < ABC.t2_min_price AND ABC.t2_min_price < ABC.t3_min_price THEN ABC.t1_min_price
        WHEN ABC.t1_min_price > ABC.t2_min_price AND ABC.t2_min_price > ABC.t3_min_price THEN ABC.t3_min_price
        ELSE ABC.t2_min_price
    END AS [min_price]
FROM (
    SELECT t1.item_id
    , (SELECT MIN(X.cost_price) fROM table1 AS X WHERE X.item_id = t1.item_id) AS [t1_min_price]
    , (SELECT MIN(Y.cost_price) fROM table2 AS Y WHERE Y.item_id = t1.item_id) AS [t2_min_price]
    , (SELECT MIN(Z.cost_price) fROM table3 AS Z WHERE Z.item_id = t1.item_id) AS [t3_min_price]
    FROM table1 AS t1
) AS ABC
```

Or,extending another user's answer:

```
SELECT X.item_id
, MIN(X.min_price) AS [lowest_price]
FROM (
    SELECT item_id, MIN(cost_price) AS [min_price] FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT item_id, MIN(cost_price) AS [min_price] FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT item_id, MIN(cost_price) AS [min_price] FROM table3
) AS X
```

The problem is when you start having more than 1 item with the same lowest price, unless that doesn't matter.  If so, just...order by something and select TOP 1 or LIMIT 1.